# Duplicates in Search Results, no duplicate contacts

Tags: profile, search-results

I've set up a search form created from a profile.

Executing the search gives a results list with 3 entries for each contact.

I have confirmed that there are not any duplicate contacts.

Is there any way to fix this?

Drupal 8 + CiviCRM

Comment: Alyx, I think you need to give a bit more detail on what you are doing to be able to work out what the problem is. What sort of search are you using?

Comment: Are you possibly not searching for contacts but for another entity such as activities or addresses? In that case the search would yield one result per activity/entity and not per contact.

Comment: I'm using a profile search form. The profile is used for individual contacts. There's no option to search for contacts or entities. Find Contacts and Advanced Search work fine.